# When setting a window height to a div its adding 10000 extra why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am making a fly left fixed menu, Its height should be change according to window size, i am using below code but its adding 10000 extra with the same window height, why its happening, div has a class `.custom-menu-primary`, check the following urls

the test url whom with i am working is http://vouclicar-5.hs-sites.com/test1 and client url is https://ww2.vouclicar.com/

```
function setMenuHeight() {
    var height = $(window).outerHeight(false);
    $('.custom-menu-primary').height(height);
}
setMenuHeight();
$(window).resize(setMenuHeight);
```

Comment: `div name .custom-menu-primary` OR div is having the class?

Comment: sorry its a class name not a div, mistakely wrote

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: Cant do it its having lot of html and css, can u check it by firebug and its console in firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're setting a margin and a padding for this element:

```
@media (max-width: 9999px)
.custom-menu-primary {
   .
   .
   .
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;
}
```

Which is giving you your ridiculous size: it's just all padding. If you look at the element's computed properties in the box model, you can see it has actually got the correct size.

Comment: Thanks @jaunt you are right i used this property before but forget to remove it, thanks again now its working fine